# Annotation Processor to add a method call

Tags: java, compiler-construction, annotations

I am writing an annotation processor, and I need `TreeTranslator.visitIdent` to place a static method call.
I think I should use `TreeMaker.Call`, or `TreeMaker.Create`, or should I use JCMethodInvocation? I couldn't find any example of how to use it.
Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

At the time your annotation processor is running, the class being inspected exists in source form only.  Thus you can't call methods on it.

Also, Annotation Processors can't directly modify the class being compiled.  Instead, you should create a new class:

```
Filer filer = env.getFiler();
PrintWriter pw = filer.createSourceFile("com.example.MyClass");
```